# How to reduce multiple case when in scala-spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, case-when

Newbie question, how do you optimize/reduce expressions like these:

```
when(x1._1,x1._2).when(x2._1,x2._2).when(x3._1,x3._2).when(x4._1,x4._2).when(x5._1,x5._2)....
.when(xX._1,xX._2).otherwise(z)
```

The x1, x2, x3, xX are maps where x1._1 is the condition and x._2 is the "then".

I was trying to save the maps in a list and then use a map-reduce but it was producing a:

```
when(x1._1,x1._2).otherwise(z) && when(x2._1,x2._2).otherwise(z)...
```

Which is wrong. I have like 10 lines of pure when case and would like to reduce that so my code is more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `foldLeft` on the maplist:

```
val maplist = List(x1, x2)  // add more x if needed

val new_col = maplist.tail.foldLeft(when(maplist.head._1, maplist.head._2))((x,y) => x.when(y._1, y._2)).otherwise(z)
```

An alternative is to use `coalesce`. If the condition is not met, null is returned by the `when` statement, and the next `when` statement will be evaluated until a non-null result is obtained.

```
val new_col = coalesce((maplist.map(x => when(x._1, x._2)) :+ z):_*)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give them a try this afternoon.

Comment: Update: Both solutions are working, thanks! I'll try to run some more tests using the alternative (coalesce), but so far so good.

Answer (score 2):

Another way by passing the otherwise as initial value for `foldLeft`:

```
val maplist = Seq(Map(col("c1") -> "value1"), Map(col("c2") -> "value2"))

val newCol = maplist.flatMap(_.toSeq).foldLeft(lit("z")) {
  case (acc, (cond, value)) => when(cond, value).otherwise(acc)
}

// gives:
// newCol: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = CASE WHEN c2 THEN value2 ELSE CASE WHEN c1 THEN value1 ELSE z END END
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a simple recursive method to assemble the nested-`when/otherwise` condition:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

def nestedCond(cols: Array[String], default: String): Column = {
  def loop(ls: List[String]): Column = ls match {
    case Nil => col(default)
    case c :: tail => when(col(s"$c._1"), col(s"$c._2")).otherwise(loop(tail))
  }
  loop(cols.toList).as("nested-cond")
}
```

Testing the method:

```
val df = Seq(
  ((false, 1), (false, 2), (true, 3), 88),
  ((false, 4), (true, 5), (true, 6), 99)
).toDF("x1", "x2", "x3", "z")

val cols = df.columns.filter(_.startsWith("x"))
// cols: Array[String] = Array(x1, x2, x3)

df.select(nestedCond(cols, "z")).show
// +-----------+
// |nested-cond|
// +-----------+
// |          3|
// |          5|
// +-----------+
```

---

Alternatively, use `foldRight` to assemble the nested-condition:

```
def nestedCond(cols: Array[String], default: String): Column =
  cols.foldRight(col(default)){ (c, acc) =>
      when(col(s"$c._1"), col(s"$c._2")).otherwise(acc)
    }.as("nested-cond")
```